# Trent Richardson Datetimepicker not working properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetimepicker

I've included Trent Richardsons Datetimepicker in my rails project but after loading the page the div containing the datetimepicker already shows. I thinks it should show only when clicked but not before. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

code containing the datetimepicker:

`<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="event_enddate_group">
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.label :enddate, :class => 'control-label' %>
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker_enddate'>
            <%= f.text_field :enddate, :class => 'form-control'%>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#event_enddate').datetimepicker({
                        locale: 'nl'
                    });
                });
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`

changed above code. Now datetimepicker is displaying at correct moment but layout still is wrong.

Comment: is there any javascript error in browser's console

Comment: No, there's no javascript error in the console

Comment: code is now in original question

Comment: give your datetimepicker class to text_field

Comment: you mean like this `<%= f.text_field :enddate, :class => 'form-control datetimepicker'%>` ?

Comment: figured it out. Thanks for your help @test.

Comment: is it solved by adding datetimepicker id to text_field?

Comment: No, solved by adding the datepicker to the textfield like `$('#event_enddate').datetimepicker({locale: 'nl'});` instead of to the div.

Comment: that is what I said.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="event_enddate_group">
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.label :enddate, :class => 'control-label' %>
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker_enddate'>
            <%= f.text_field :enddate, :class => 'form-control event_enddate' %>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('.event_enddate').datetimepicker({
                        locale: 'nl'
                    });
                });
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

always use class instead of id while doing any jquery or javascript functioning